# jQuery fails in executing html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am doing an image gallery viewer, with little thumbnails, one medium-sized viewer, and if you click on that viewer, it fadeIn a div that displays image in full size.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

My problem is that when I click on a little thumbnail, then I click on the medium-sized photo, i.e. mediumpic (in order to fadeIn() the invisible div), jQuery fails in executing html() and fadeIn(). However, it works only when document is ready (that is, with photo#1 that was loaded in the viewer by default). But when I click on any of those little thumbnails, it ruins it. What is happening there?

My HTML is the following:

```
echo "<div class='largepic_div'></div>";
echo "<div class='viewer'><img class='mediumpic'src='upload/photos/".$dbphoto1."'></div>
echo "<div class='allpics'>";

echo "<div class='thumbnail_viewer'><img class='thumbnail_item' 
src='upload/photos/".$dbphoto1."' height='60'></div>";

echo "<div class='thumbnail_viewer'><img class='thumbnail_item' 
src='upload/photos/".$dbphoto2."' height='60'></div></div>";
```

My jQuery is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.thumbnail_item').click(function(){

    $('.viewer').html("<img class='mediumpic' src='upload/photos/"+ $(this).attr('src').split('/')\[2\] +"'>");

    });

$('.mediumpic').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.largepic_div').html("<img src='upload/photos/"+ $(this).attr('src').split('/')\[2\] +"'>").fadeIn();

    });

$('body').click(function(){
        $('.largepic_div').fadeOut();
        }); 
});
```

Comment: just corrected the $ sign for the php variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the click handler to mediumpic on document ready, but when you click the thumbnail, you are removing the img element and replace it by a new one... therefore the handler is no longer attached.

You can either attach the handler again after you click on the thumbnail, or keep the original element and just replace the src of the img element (instead of using .html()).

UPDATE 1:

Method 1:

```
$('.thumbnail_item').click(function(){
    $('.viewer').html("<img class='mediumpic' src='upload/photos/"+ $(this).attr('src').split('/')\[2\] +"'>");
    $('.mediumpic').click(mediumpicHandler);
});

$('.mediumpic').click(mediumpicHandler);

var mediumpicHandler = function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.largepic_div').html("<img src='upload/photos/"+ $(this).attr('src').split('/')\[2\] +"'>").fadeIn();
}
```

Method 2:

```
$('.thumbnail_item').click(function(){
    $('.viewer img').attr("src","upload/photos/"+ $(this).attr('src').split('/')\[2\]);
});
```

Warning: I didn't actually test the above code... it's just an idea on where to take it.

UPDATE 2:

I just showed how to fix the problem with the thumbnail/medium pic interaction... you would need to apply the same fix to the medium/large pic interaction too.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. As for your second option, do you mean: go into the child of "largepic_div" and change its "src" attribute to another path? Thanks a lot regards

Comment: I actually used your method 2 and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for that! I have have one question about when I replace the img by another, why is the handler is no longer attached? I had assigned the click event to a class. I expected it to be working all the time but it wasn't. Is it because this is executed upon document.ready? Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, on document ready, jQuery finds all elements with the mediumpic class and attaches the handler to them.  After that, it will not execute any more.  In short, the handler gets attached to the elements, not the class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, I finally got it. Regards